# Is it safe to assume that a page is redirecting if a "Location" header is received?

Tags: http, redirect, https, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I'm creating a JavaScript function to follow redirects using Node.JS's native HTTPS module. Is it safe to assume if there is a "Location" header that the page is redirecting, or should I also be checking that the status code is 300-399? Is there any other reason I'd receive a "Location" header other than a redirect?

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed other cases, such as 201 Created.